# Como fazer colisão 2D de Tiles em C++

Tags: c, c++, detecção-de-colisão, sdl

Olá.

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para obter colisão de Tiles em C++.

Estou utilizando uma engine feita pelo meu amigo, mesmo assim, gostaria de saber como fazer.

Estou utilizando o SDL 2!

Grato desde já

Thiago

Comment: Olá Thiago. Bem vindo ao SOPT. Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida? Você não sabe como definir os tiles na "engine feita pelo seu amigo" (aliás, ela já faz detecção de colisões?), não sabe como funciona a colisão de forma geral ou fez algo que não está funcionando como esperado? A sua pergunta está muito abstrata, e vai receber respostas igualmente abstratas. Aliás, alguém poderia te indicar pra ler as demais perguntas que tratam de colisão. Tem algumas já: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detec%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-colis%C3%A3o

Comment: A Engine desenvolvida pelo seu amigo tem alguma classe que armazena retangulos ou informações sobre o tile? Se possivel coloque a classe que você ultiliza para armazena-los

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No geral o sistema de colisão mais simple atravez de retangulo que pode ser facilmente adaptado para utilizar em tiles funciona da seguinte maneira:

```
class Rectangle
{
public:
    int X, Y; // Posição
    int W, H; // Largura e Altura
};

bool Colisao(Rectangle A, Rectangle B)
{
    if (A.X + A.W > B.X && A.Y + A.H > B.Y)
    {
        if (A.X < B.X + B.W && A.Y < B.Y + B.H)
        {
            // Houve Colisão!
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Não Houve Colisão
    return false;
}
```

Verifique se a engine de seu amigo tem alguma classe que armazena retângulo ou tiles, se tiver basta adaptar a função "Colisão" com as classes da engine de seu amigo, mas verifique se ele não fez alguma função de detecção de colisão ja que a maioria das engines tráz funções de gerenciamento de física.

Comment: Obrigado. Mas conversei com meu amigo e ele deu um jeito. Só estou com dúvida de como fazer uma gravidade 2D corretamente, mas mesmo assim, obrigado =D